# if-else flow in promise (bluebird)

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

This is a short version of my code.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

if (conditionA) {
  fs.writeFileAsync(file, jsonData).then(function() {
    return functionA();
  });
} else {
  functionA();
}
```

Both conditions call `functionA`. Is there way to avoid else condition? I can do `fs.writeFileSync` but I am looking for a non-blocking solution.

Comment: Promise is designed for async task control. Why use the sync fucntion? You can simply check the return value of `writeFileAsync`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
(conditionA 
  ? fs.writeFileAsync(file, jsonData)
  : Promise.resolve())
.then(functionA);
```

which is short for

```
var waitFor;
if (conditionA)
    waitFor = fs.writeFileAsync(file, jsonData);
else
    waitFor = Promise.resolve(undefined); // wait for nothing,
                                          // create fulfilled promise
waitFor.then(function() {
    return functionA();
});
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a typescript or bluebird problem, but when I just simply do `Promise.resolve()` I get an error `error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ <U>(onFulfill?: (value: Object) => U | PromiseLike<U>, onReject?: (error: any) => U | PromiseLi...' has no compatible call signatures.` But `Promise.resolve({})` works. Any ideas?

Comment: @ahong that's a Typescript problem telling you that it can't derive the type for `Promise.resolve()` - try `Promise.resolve(undefined)` or casting it explicitly to whatever you want.

Answer (score 10):

While other suggestions here work, personally I prefer the following.

```
Promise.resolve(function(){
  if (condition) return fs.writeFileAsync(file, jsonData);
}())
.then()
```

It has the disadvantage of always creating this additional promise (rather minor IMO) but looks much cleaner to my eye.  You can also add other conditions/logic easily inside the IIFE.

**EDIT**

After implementing things like this for a long time now I have definitely changed to something slightly clearer.  The initial promise is created regardless so it is much clearer to simply do:

```js
/* Example setup */

var someCondition = (Math.random()*2)|0;
var value = "Not from a promise";
var somePromise = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('Promise value'), 3000));


/* Example */

Promise.resolve()
.then(() => {
  if (someCondition) return value;
  return somePromise;
})
.then((result) => document.body.innerHTML = result);
```

```html
Initial state
```

Actually, in the your case it would simply be

```
if (someCondition) return somePromise;
```

inside of the first .then() function.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use [`Promise.all()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#props---promise) with conditional function

```
var condition = ...;

var maybeWrite = function(condition, file, jsonData){
    return (condition) ? fs.writeFileAsync(file, jsonData) : Promise.resolve(true);
}

Promise.all([maybeWrite(condition, file, jsonData),functionA()])
.then(function(){
    // here 'functionA' was called, 'writeFileAsync' was maybe called
})
```

Or, if you want `functionA` only called after the file maybe was written you can separate:

```
maybeWrite(condition, file, jsonData)
.then(function(){
    // here file may have been written, you can call 'functionA'
    return functionA();
})
```

Comment: My *only* issue with this approach is maintainability.  You sign yourself up for having to 'untangle' stuff down the line.  Which is one of the benefits of Promise chains - your logic is linear feeling.