# How to skip next .then() if boolean is false in fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, if-statement, promise, fetch

```
// foo.json
[]
// bar.json
[
  {
    "name": "bar",
    "type": "whatever" 
  }
]
function getJSON(path) {
  return fetch(`http://localhost:4000/admin/${path}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
}
function getStart() {
  getJSON('foo')
    .then(data => {
      if (data.length == 0) {
        return getJSON('bar')
        // Look at bar.json and access to next .then() method
      }
      console.log('Access Denied')
      // skip the next .then() method and exit.
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data, 'another then path')
    })
}
```

I added `if` statement inside of first `.then()` for giving different path depends on the foo's `data.length` is 0 or not.

A problem is the code always accesses to the second `.then()` whatever the boolean is `true` or `false`.

This is the result:

> Access Denied index.js:31
>
> undefined "another then path" index.js:34

I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257412/how-to-handle-the-if-else-in-promise-then) like me but he uses `promise`, not `fetch`, and I don't know how to use `reject` in `fetch` clause.

Any tips to fix this problem?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 2):

You could use `throw` for trigger an error in Promise. Example of code :

```
const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw 'Uh-oh!';
});

promise1.catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
// expected output: Uh-oh!
```

For your code :

```
function getStart() {
  getJSON('foo')
    .then(data => {
      if (data.length === 0) {
        return getJSON('bar')
        // Look at bar.json and access to next .then() method
      } else {
         console.log('Access Denied');
         throw new Error('Access Denied');
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data, 'another then path')
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('Error', e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot about `throw` keyword. Thank you so much. It helps a lot.