# Conditional then in promises (bluebird)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

What I want to do

```
getFoo()
  .then(doA)
  .then(doB)
  .if(ifC, doC)
  .else(doElse)
```

I think the code is pretty obvious? Anyway:

I want to do call a promise when a specific condition (also a promise) is given. I could probably do something like

```
getFoo()
  .then(doA)
  .then(doB)
  .then(function(){
    ifC().then(function(res){
    if(res) return doC();
    else return doElse();
  });
```

But that feels pretty verbose.

I'm using bluebird as promise library. But I guess if there is something like that it'll be the same in any promise library.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26600424/1330674), here's what i came up with for an optional then:

> Note: if your condition function really needs to be a promise, look at @TbWill4321's answer

answer for **optional** `then()`

```
getFoo()
  .then(doA)
  .then(doB)
  .then((b) => { ifC(b) ? doC(b) : Promise.resolve(b) }) // to be able to skip doC()
  .then(doElse) // doElse will run if all the previous resolves
```

improved answer from @jacksmirk for **conditional** `then()`

```
getFoo()
  .then(doA)
  .then(doB)
  .then((b) => { ifC(b) ? doC(b) : doElse(b) }); // will execute either doC() or doElse()
```

> **EDIT:** I suggest you have a look at Bluebird's discussion on having a `promise.if()` [HERE](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/1055)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to have nested `.then` calls, since it seems like `ifC` returns a `Promise` anyways:

```
getFoo()
  .then(doA)
  .then(doB)
  .then(ifC)
  .then(function(res) {
    if (res) return doC();
    else return doElse();
  });
```

You could also do some legwork up front:

```
function myIf( condition, ifFn, elseFn ) {
  return function() {
    if ( condition.apply(null, arguments) )
      return ifFn();
    else
      return elseFn();
  }
}

getFoo()
  .then(doA)
  .then(doB)
  .then(ifC)
  .then(myIf(function(res) {
      return !!res;
  }, doC, doElse ));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599798/if-else-flow-in-promise-bluebird)

An example with your code:

```
getFoo()
  .then(doA)
  .then(doB)
  .then(condition ? doC() : doElse());
```

The elements in the condition must be defined before starting the chain.