# What is the idiom for optional asynchronous preprocessing in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, idioms

Let's say I have to do some computation, which for example consists of computing A (asynchronously, with callback) and then when A is computed, computing B (also async with callback).

The problem is A is optional, if there is no data for it, I should jump right at computing B.

Currently I use pretty ugly code with doubled B execution, something like this:

```
if (A)
  computeA(A,() => computeB(B,() => console.log("done.")));
else
  computeB(B,() => console.log("done."));
```

I am asking to avoid baking up some my solution, which would not be recognized by any JS developer :-) Is there some idiom for it?

Comment: Closely related: [if-else flow in promise](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26599798/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be also done quite easily with promises:

```
if (A)
   p = A();
else
   p = Promise.resolve(defaultValue)

p.then(B).then(done)
```

assuming A and B both return promises. If they are traditional callback-acceptors, you have to promisify them.

Comment: Great! I was hoping for such form, so thank you very much.

Comment: Cool. It wasn't obvious Promises could be used in the original question. This is a much better answer.

Comment: @naomik, why did you delete your answer? It was good! Please, could you put it back -- when you need to press the pedal to the metal, dropping any allocations is a valuable thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially continuation passing style. Because the continuation is just a function, you could assign the chain that always happens to a var and then reuse it in each branch of the `if`

```
let next = () => computeB(B,() => console.log("done."))
if (A)
  computeA(A, next)
else
  next()
```

---

**a tiny continuation monad**

Continuations are really fun to work with in JavaScript and they express particular problems in very meaningful ways.

Here's a tiny implementation of the continuation monad `cont` that allows you to define all sorts of functions you wish to chain in your computation.

`when` is the crucial function here as it allows you to specify a predicate that conditionally binds another function in the chain.

Below, we will start with a continuation of `0`, (`cont(0)`) then add `1` only if the current continuation's value is less than `3` – subsequent calls to `when (lt (3)) (f)` will return a continuation of an unaltered value

```js
// cont :: a -> cont a
const cont = x =>
  k => k (x)
  
// when :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> cont a) -> a -> cont a
const when = p => f => x =>
  p (x) ? f (x) : cont (x)

// contAdd :: Number -> Number -> cont Number
const contAdd = x => y =>
  cont (x + y)
  
// lt :: Number -> Number -> Bool
const lt = x => y =>
  y < x
  
// contLog :: a -> a
const contLog = x =>
  (console.log(x), cont(x))
  
// demo
cont (0)
  (contLog) // => 0
  (when (lt (3)) (contAdd (1)))
  (contLog) // => 1
  (when (lt (3)) (contAdd (1)))
  (contLog) // => 2
  (when (lt (3)) (contAdd (1)))
  (contLog) // => 3
  (when (lt (3)) (contAdd (1)))
  (contLog) // => 3
  (when (lt (3)) (contAdd (1)))
  (contLog) // => 3
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to keep the order of the calls -- A first, then B? Here of course it is easy to see the reversed nature, but in real code it could lead to a surprise.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to setup a queue to chain asynchronous calculations using promises like this:

```
function compute(queue, previousResult) {
    if (!queue.length) return previousResult;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Get Operation
        var operation = queue.shift();
        //If there is nothing to calculate just resolve the promise
        if (!operation[0]) {
            resolve(0);
        }
        //Execute the computation function and give it the 
        //resolve callback to resolve the promise when the calculations done
        operation[1](operation[0], previousResult || null, resolve);
    }).then(result => {
        //Call the next calculation with result of the previous one
        return compute(queue, result);
    });
}
```

Then:

```
var A = 10;

function computeA(a, previous, resolve) {
    $.get('https://httpbin.org/get').then(function() {
        resolve(a*10);
    });
}

var B = 20;

function computeB(b, previous, resolve) {
    resolve(previous + b * 10);
}

var C = 20;

function computeC(c, previous, resolve) {
    resolve(previous + c * 10);
}


compute([
    [A, computeA],
    [B, computeB],
    [C, computeC]
]).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
function compute(queue, previousResult) {
    if (!queue.length) return previousResult;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Get Operation
        var operation = queue.shift();
        //If there is nothing to calculate just resolve the promise
        if (!operation[0]) {
            resolve(0);
        }
        //Execute the computation function
        operation[1](operation[0], previousResult || null, resolve);
    }).then(result => {
        //Call the next calculation with result of the previous one
        return compute(queue, result);
    });
}

var A = 10;

function computeA(a, previous, resolve) {
    $.get('https://httpbin.org/get').then(function() {
        resolve(a*10);
    });
}

var B = 20;

function computeB(b, previous, resolve) {
    resolve(previous + b * 10);
}

var C = 20;

function computeC(c, previous, resolve) {
    resolve(previous + c * 10);
}


compute([
    [A, computeA],
    [B, computeB],
    [C, computeC]
]).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```