# Is it possible to get value returned by .resolve() outside the .then() scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I'm using Node.js and q library.

I have a code that looks like this:

```
checkIfThingExists(function(idForAThing){
  if(idForAThing){
    updateThingData(idForAThing);
  } else {
    createThing(function(idForAThing){
      updateThingData(idForAThing);
    });
  }
})
```

As you can see I need to call updateThingData(); twice.

Is there a way I can use promises to call `updateThingData()` just once, for example something like this? Of course this does not work and `idForAThing` is always `undefined` when the if statement runs:

```
checkIfThingExists(function(idForAThing){

  if(!idForAThing){
    createThing().then(function(newIdForAThing){
      idForAThing = newIdForAThing
    })
  }

  updateThingData(idForAThing);
})
```

Comment: No, it's not possible to get the value before the `then` callback, that's the whole point of promises. However, you [can use a promise conditionally and carry on asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39621747/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what is happening is the `.then` method is a callback.  It doesn't get called until after `updateThingData` is called.

You could instead create a promise chain that will resolve after it has the ID.  Then chain the next `.then` callback to call updateThingData.  Here is an example of that:

```js
checkIfThingExists(function(idForAThing){
  return Q.resolve() // or Promise.resolve if you were using the browser implementation
    .then(function() {
      if(!idForAThing) return createThing()
      return idForAThing
    })
    .then(updateThingData)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return in any case a promise.
So:

```
checkIfThingExists(function(idForAThing){
  var promise

  if(!idForAThing)
    promise = createThing()
  else
    promise = Promise.resolve(idForAThing)

  promise.then(function(id){
    updateThingData(id)})
  }
```