# Suggestion practice: make sure a promise needed to be called only if a certain condition happened has resolved before going on

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a promise whose abstract code is something like:

```
const myPromise = (input) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   //does something with input and provide some result
   if (everything_is_ok) resolve(result);
   else reject(error);
});
```

And this is the abstract flow of a procedure on my script:

```
let myVar;
//some code instructions...
myVar = something; //this comes as result of some code
if (condition){
    //(once promises resolves) compute function does something with pr_output
    //and provides another resulting output that gets stored on myVar for further computation
    myPromise(takes myVar or some data as input here).then((pr_output)=>{myVar=compute(pr_output);});
}
//further operations with myVar follow here...
//AND, if condition was true, I want/need to be sure that the promise has resolved
//and the computation in its "then" instruction ended as well before going on...
```

So now the question is:
 **(How) is it possible to go on without having to call a subsequent function?**
I mean I know I could simply do something like:

```
if (condition){
    myPromise(takes myVar or some data as input here).then((pr_output)=>{myVar=compute(pr_output);
        anotherProcedure(myVar); // <== THIS IS IT
    });
} else anotherPocedure(myVar) // <== AND... THIS IS IT TOO
```

So I'd basically put every computation that comes after the condition check inside that `anotherProcedure(myVar)` and call it (providing myVar as input):

- in the promise's `then` if *condition* was **true**
- or in the `else` branch if *condition* was **false**

Is this the only way I can go or **is it possible to avoid having to wrap the further computation inside that another procedure and call it that way?**
(If it is, please show me how to do it)
Thank you

Comment: You may want to take a look at [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: If `myPromise` does validation, why does it need to be asynchronous?

Comment: If you just want to avoid *naming* the `anotherProcedure` function, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26599798/1048572). If you want to avoid having to write an (anonymous) function altogether, your only choice is `async`/`await`.

Comment: Yeah, @tevemadar you're right (I had tried at first but had a bug and thought I was making some mistake in using `async/await` before realizing what was really wrong... +1

Comment: @Bergi you really must be the `promise` evangelist man :-D Thank you very much for linking that question in your comment, it looks very interesting to me +1 here and +1 there ...and thank you again! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you can simply use async / await:

```
 (async function() {
    if(condition) {
      const myVar = compute( await myPromise());
    }
    anotherProcedure();
 })();
```

Comment: I like this way to do it, thank you very much and sorry for my delay. I had tried something similar before asking but things seemed not to work and I thought I was doing something wrong with `async/await` ... After your reply, I ended up discovering a (very silly but hard to see) bug in the compute code *facepalm* :-p ... Thank you again, accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Create *just one* `Promise` chain, and you can tack on `anotherPocedure(myVar)` to the end of it. If the condition is true, then return the `myPromise` invocation (thus "pausing" the `Promise` chain until it resolves), else don't return anything (thus running the next `.then` which has `anotherPocedure` immediately). Translating your lower code, it could look like

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    if (condition) return myPromise(takes myVar or some data as input here)
      .then((pr_output) => {
         myVar = compute(pr_output);
      });
  })
  .then(() => anotherPocedure(myVar));
```

Though it would be more readable to extract the first `.then` into its own function, for better readability:

```
const tryCompute = () => {
  if (condition) return myPromise(takes myVar or some data as input here)
    .then((pr_output) => {
      myVar = compute(pr_output);
    });
  else return Promise.resolve();
};

tryCompute()
  .then(() => anotherPocedure(myVar));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, if I could I'd accept this one as well but I can only choose one and liked Jonas W. example very much... (Have my upvote, ofc.)