# JS Promises - how to make a axios call wait?

Tags: javascript, promise, wait

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.
In my app I want to check if a some data has been previously loaded up (from an API call elsewhere in the app). If not, then I want to load the data up. However, I don't want to go any further in the app until I am assured that I have the data.

So the pseudocode looks like this.

```
if (!dataIsloaded) {
  axios.get("/api/getData").then((data) => {
    saveData(data); 
    dataIsLoaded=true;
  });
}

// don't go any further until I'm assured I have the data
```

Can someone provide a code snippet how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/26600424/1048572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to wait, simply run your processing after the data are there:

```
if (!dataIsloaded) { // First retrieve the data
    axios.get("/api/getData").then((data) => {
        saveData(data); 
        dataIsLoaded=true;
        doSomethingWithTheData(data); // Finally use the data
    });
}
else { // Directly use the data
    doSomethingWithTheData(data);
}

...

function doSomethingWithTheData(data) {
    ...
}
```