# What are the advantages of using async/await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm reading several articles and seeing some videos about how to use async/await in JavaScript and seems that the only reason is to transform asynchronous code in synchronous code (and make code more readable but this is not intended to be discussed in this question).

So, I would like to understand if there are more reasons on using these statements because, in my understanding, if we have Promises to make async calls and improve the performance of our code, why we want to convert it again to synchronous code?

Comment: I believe it's nothing but syntactic sugar. Promises are really hard to understand completely and many people never really get them fully right and good old nested callbacks don't scale nicely.

Comment: It's not synchronous code. It's code that's running sequentially and asynchronously but still following control structures. Nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Why do you think promises improve performance? They only make it simpler to deal with asynchronous results.

Comment: @Bergi I'm also interested in how promises improve performance. Unless OP means "they don't hold up the thread" which could lead to the display freezing (in the browser)...but that just means "don't await if you have a very long task"

Comment: @Bergi Promises improve performance in the way you can run some different actions in the main thread running all of them asynchronous, so you are able to improve the time your function takes to execute.

Comment: @jaloplo No, promises don't do that. All promise and non-promise code runs on the main thread. Promises don't make anything asynchronous, they only provide a convenient wrapper around tasks that are already inherently asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi afaik, Promise.all method allows to run more than one task at a time. It will resolve when the longest task ends so you will not waste time running synchronously. Let me know if I'm wrong. I followed this video as the master for learning async/await https://youtu.be/vn3tm0quoqE

Comment: @jaloplo No, `Promise.all` doesn't run anything. It just creates a promise from an array of promises, promises that have already been created and (usually) started to run things. But it's those things that need to be asynchronous to run concurrently - `Promise.all` doesn't change anything about that.

Comment: @Bergi totally agree with you, if methods are not async is not possible to run them async but, as I said, Promise.all makes able to save time running several async methods in the sense that you need their results independently.

Comment: @jaloplo It's possible to do the same without promises, so I'd say the speedup is not due to promises. Sure, `Promise.all` is *much* more convenient than writing the wait-for-all-results code by hand :-)

Comment: @Bergi like to see a sample

Comment: @jaloplo `let count=0; function done() { console.log("callback", count); if (++count == 2) console.log("Both done"); } setTimeout(done, 1000); setTimeout(done, 1500);` - the two timeouts happen concurrently. Or use the async.js library or so for these things.

Comment: @Bergi that's a trick. That's not the same as Promises, you execute ```done``` function after 1000 milliseconds and after 1500 milliseconds. You have to add the time the function consumes so it's more than you set for them. Definitely, that's not the same.

Comment: @jaloplo No, the two timeouts are occurring at the same time - try yourself. The times do not add, the "both done" logs when both of them have called the callback. It's not a trick, it's exactly the same mechanism that `Promise.all` uses internally to wait for multiple asynchronous promise resolutions.

Comment: @Bergi, you are totally right. Thanks for letting me understand how it works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be considered to be not *actually* synchronous. When you `await` something that is `async`, it gets added to a microtask queue. It does not run on the main thread, meaning other things can occur (click events, rendering, etc.)

Here is a fantastic talk that can explain it in further detail
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0

`await/async` are often referred to as syntactic sugar, and let us wait for something (e.g. an API call), giving us the illusion that it is synchronous.

Comment: the video is unavailable or at least for me.

Comment: really good and useful video explaining the basics of javascript, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think async await increases the readability of the code. In some promise-callback uses, you can find yourself in a very long chain, which can be called a callback pit. it is up to you to consider whether to use async-await.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you need multiple actions inside single functions, some of them may be asynchronous and some may be synchronous. Let's say you have following code with promises.

```
getUser().then(user => {
    getOrders({
        user: user
    }).then(orders => {
        console.log(orders)
    })
})
```

now what if you want orders to be fetched only if a condition is true, but let further code run as it is, then if you are using promises, you have to create a separate function and then call that function like this

```
function logOrders(orders) {
    console.log(orders)
}


getUser().then(user => {
    if (user.hasOrders) {
        getOrders({
            user: user
        }).then(logOrders)
    } else {
        logOrders([])
    }
})
```

but using async/await you can do it like this

```
(async () => {

    const user = await getUser();
    let orders = [];

    if (user.hasOrders) {
        orders = await getOrders({
            user: user
        })
    }

    console.log(orders)

})()
```

Comment: No, [you don't need a separate function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26600424/1048572).

Comment: How will you do that?

Comment: you have to wait conditionally for getOrders() to complete

Comment: Did you check the link? Also, `getUser().then(user => user.hasOrders ? getOrders({user}) : []).then(orders => console.log(orders));`

Comment: how will you access the user variable inside the last then method?

Comment: See [How do I access previous promise results in a `.then()` chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) For example, `getUser().then(user => (user.hasOrders ? getOrders({user}) : Promise.resolve([])).then(orders => console.log(user, orders)));` (Notice that your separate function doesn't achieve this at all)

Comment: that's what async and await do

Comment: Yes, `async`/`await` makes it simpler, it's one of the great uses that improves readability (see my accepted answer to the other question). But no, a separate function is not necessary for conditional promises, and still it's only a readability advantage which the OP was not asking about.

Comment: I explained how the same thing can be done with better readability via both Promises and async/await

Comment: and obviously creating separate function is more readable than the method you shared

Comment: But the fact remains that your statement--"...you have to create a separate function..."--is incorrect.