# How to resolve promise in two cases?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is a condition:

```
let needPromise = true;
```

And promise function:

```
   getLayerId(): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             if(needPromise) {
                  //
             }
        });
    }
```

Somewhere I need to get `string` from promise:

```
getLayerId.then((layerId: string => {});
```

I need to await promise in case when `needPromise` true, for example opening dialog window and resolve promise instantly if `needPromise = false`. How to do that?

Comment: *resolve promise instantly* that's impossible. The reason these exists is that they are async calls and rely on an external party (http more than likely) to return before they can continue.

Comment: how about not make a primise call if needPromise if false, if needPromise is true skip getLayerId()

Comment: Could you share this example?

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26600424/1048572). However, your question is really unclear, as we don't know the context