# Conditional flow of control in promise chain

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I want to write a long promise chain in which some items will be skipped based on a condition. Something like this, unfortunately, this is not valid syntax:

```
function f(condition) {
    A()
    .then (B)
    if (condition) {
        .then(C)
        .then(D)
    }
    .then(E)
}
```

What is the most graceful way to do what I want?  I already have a way to handle data flow, so I'm not worried about the fact that the result of B and the result of D may not look similar. It's just control flow that I'm concerned with.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: The most graceful? Use `async`/`await` syntax

Comment: Otherwise, see [if-else flow in promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26599798/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `if` statement inside the `.then()` function.

```
function f(condition) {
  A()
    .then(B)
    .then(arg => {
      if (condition) {
        return C(arg).then(D);
      } else {
        return arg;
      }
    })
    .then(E)
}
```

Comment: Barmar, you're close, but actually I wanted to skip both C and D (no else) if the condition is false.